# how to position Matlab GUI window at top of screen?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I used Matlab GUIDE to create a GUI.
It is displayed mid-screen.

How can I position it at the top of the screen; so that the top edge of the  GUI window is at top of screen.

It will be used on different Windows 7 computers with different screen resolutions.

I tried to set `hObject.Position(2)` but it doesn't do what I want.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way would be to use [movegui](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movegui.html?refresh=true) in the `OpeningFcn` of your GUI with the appropriate argument, i.e. using either 'north', 'northeast' or 'northwest'.

The calling syntax is quite simple, using the handles to the figure created. In GUIDE, the default name for figures is "figure1", so in your case the code would look like this (unless you changed the figure's name):

```
movegui(handles.figure1,'northwest') %// or whatever
```

Note that `movegui` calls the following 3 functions to get the screen size and monitor positions/units:

```
screensize = get(0, 'ScreenSize');
monitors = get(0,'MonitorPositions');
old0units = get(0, 'Units');
```

So you could do the same to make the calculations yourself in order to place the figure precisely where you want if the above solution is not sufficient for you.

Comment: This is good, but it leaves a gap between top and left edge.  How can I set position exactly?   I tried to set hObject.Position(2) but it doesn't do what I want.

Comment: are you using a release older than R2014? If so it is some kind of bug. Check [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/161639) for a workaround. I will add it to the answer if it works for you